# How to restore a previous session of Outlook after a crash? I had always been able to reopen items but Outlook just said it didn't save before closing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, microsoft-outlook-2016, open, recent-items

So, I was always able to reopen previously emails from Outlook, which I did use a lot since Outlook liked crashing. However, one day Outlook just said through a notification it did not save the previous session and when Outlook opened, there was no prompt to  "reopen your last items". It would be nice if I could somehow get Outlook to reopen those previous items. I am not sure why Outlook did not save the session this time after crashing. Do I have to into the %appdata% files to locate the previous session, if is even available? If anyone can give a solution to this first world problem, it would be great. It would make tracking emails I had open a whole lot easier.

Best,
an Outlook email person

Answer (score 1):

The option to restore previous items is default. Make sure it has not changed.

Now Outlook does not crash regularly (not for me, acquaintances, or any history I read).

If the option remains set to "open previous items" and you experience crashing, then you probably should repair Outlook (Office).

Uninstall Office, restart, Install and Patch Office and then see if Outlook is better behaved and if Restore Previous has returned.

If the Previous Items are not there, there is likely nothing you can do.

Here is a screen shot of the option (General) to help you check

[image: Outlook option to reopen previous item]

Comment: Thank you for replying and I did check if this option is on. It does say to "ask me if I want to reopen previous items" and my question was what do I do if it did not ask me this when I restarted Outlook? It did not say this even though it is checked. Is there a way to restore what was open when I open Outlook? I know there is way to do this for browsers by going into the folders to restore a previous session. Can you do this for Outlook?

Comment: The setting I suggested works for Outlook. It is not, however, browser related.

Comment: okay, thank you. I am not sure though what do I do when it does NOT save, when I had the option to ask me if I want to reopen. There was a notification on the PC it did not save. Then, Outlook opened with no items open. Is there a way to restore a previous session?

Comment: System Restore does not usually affect an app like Outlook. All you can to is repair Outlook (Office) as suggested and then if no previous version, there is probably nothing you can do. I did amend my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Alright, and thank you for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: If you think the reply is helpful, please remember to mark it as an answer.