# In Outlook, is there a way to open a previous session with items if the option to "ask me to reopen last items" does not appear when starting Outlook?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, email, crash, microsoft-outlook-2016

This option is already selected in the options yet Outlook did not save the last open items. Is there a way to get the previous session for Outlook?

Comment: Please don't post duplicates [How to restore a previous session of Outlook after a crash? I had always been able to reopen items but Outlook just said it didn't save before closing](https://superuser.com/questions/1833999/how-to-restore-a-previous-session-of-outlook-after-a-crash-i-had-always-been-ab) If the answer wasn't helpful make sure to comment to let the author know and eventually improve his answer.